# Database design with multi password for a unique user

Tags: mysql, database, security, passwords

Is it possible to design a database in way where a unique user has multiple password and given the password something different happens for each of them? during the authentification for instance.

The password will be in relation with another table.

I was wondering if this design can lead to security issues.

Comment: How would you handle a "I forgot my password" functionnality ?

Comment: The number of users in my case will not be more than 50, so it's not a problem, I will handle that manually. But it looks like an issue otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as far as the design goes, sure it it possible.  Have a FK from your users table to your password table that is the users ID, that way you will have a 1 to many relationship to passwords, then have a role or action on the password table that tells the system what to do.

As far as security is concerned, it's not really any more dangerous than storing your passwords in a single table, actually thinking about it, it's possibly safer since you are separating the login information of the user from the users password/passwords.  Just be sure to follow proper security guidelines for each password, and the design is safe enough.  I actually often use a separate table to store passwords for my users.